# Eclipselink cache is not used for Criteria API queries

Tags: caching, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I am using Criteria API for creation of queries which are usually not using PK as identifier. I am not able to force eclipselink store result to cache.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Book> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(MetadataTextValue.class);
Root<Book> root = criteriaQuery.from(MetadataTextValue.class);
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(root.get("value"),value.getValue()));
TypedQuery<Book> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
MetadataTextValue metadataTextValue = typedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

But it works for:

```
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select m from MetadataTextValue m where m.value = :value");
    query.setParameter("value",value.getValue());
    return (MetadataTextValue)query.getSingleResult();
```

So there should not be problem with the entity and value itself. I tried to debug Eclipselink search and when using criteria API, after first cache miss result is added to cache, but next search for same value is again cache miss, but is not added.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/queries004.htm says "Criteria queries are dynamic queries and do not perform as well as static named queries, or even dynamic parametrized JPQL which benefit from EclipseLink's parse cache." so it looks like it is not possible.

Comment: Which cache are you trying to hit?  EclipseLink has object caches, query caches, query result caches..  If using JPA 2.1, you can even add your criteria query as a named query for reuse as described here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#Add_Named_Query

Comment: One major difference between your criteria query and the JPQL query is its use of the query.setParameter method.  In the criteria query you are adding the value directly to the query, which prevents it from being reused.  You should add it to the query as a parameter: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Named_parameter_criteria_example

Comment: I want to hit 2nd Level Entity cache. Maybe I can think about adding named query with dynamic name. I am using https://github.com/jaxio/jpa-query-by-example now, so Ill have to rewrite it or not use it. I tried your second hint with adding parameter to query, but it did not help to use cache :(

Comment: My goal is searching for entity by all given atributes, number of given attributes may be different. For User entity sometimes I want to search by surname, next time by email then by login, if more are given, then by all of them. This is easy with criteria API, but for named query it seems to me I have to define 7 queries at least (one for each surname, login, email, then combination of 2 from these, then all 3)

Comment: yes, if you want the benifit of not having to reparse your JPA query all the time, you would define a query for the most common usages.  You could then name it based on its parameters, so that the string used to look up the query is dynamic.  Or you could create a query that accepts all parameters such that ""(someUnusedValue = :value OR m.value = :value) AND  (someUnusedValue = :value2 OR m.value2 = :value2)".  Null may not work, as it requires special handling on most databases, but you could always try (:value is null OR m.value = :value) AND  (:value2 is null OR m.value2 = :value2)